# Recompilation of query plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We recently released a new indexed view into production to help the performance of a particular query and although performance has significantly improved we noticed that a service call would occasionally take up to one second.

I did some investigation and I could see that the instances where the service call took up to a second to execute coincided with a compile of the query plan. Once I knew that I monitored it and could see that it was being recompiled due to updated statistics.

The data in this table changes constantly so I would expect the stats would be updated seeing as auto create statistics is enabled, but I just wondered what people do in this type of scenario. Is a query hint such as KEEPFIXED PLAN (not possible in my case) or would a plan guide help?

This isn't a huge issue as we would see a very large amount of calls per minute with a few being affected by the recompilation. It's more out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable async statistics update and see whether the behavior persists

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-2017#auto_update_statistics_async

With this enabled the optimizer doesn't wait for statistics to update before compiling the plan. The downside is you might execute a query with a plan generated with out of date stats

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look into that.